# VB.NET solution to - " WCF service default project setup example does not work"

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I know this has been asked before and I've went through 2 of the only answered questions here with a fine tooth comb, and many hours later trying every possible solution, I'm still not able to get the default WCF project to work on VS2012 (see error in title).

In a nutshell: 
All I want to do is get the default WCF Application project to work in VisualStudio 2012 Pro.

What I've tried:
Changing the WEB.CONFIG end to add the following (this apparently, works for most, but not me)

```
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="Service1">
  <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
      contract="Service1.IService1"/>
  <endpoint 
    address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding" 
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

And the following:

```
  <behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

The iService1.vb code (didn't change the default):

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType

    ' TODO: Add your service operations here

End Interface


<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType

<DataMember()>
Public Property BoolValue() As Boolean

<DataMember()>
Public Property StringValue() As String

End Class
```

The markup for the Service1.svc:

```
    <%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="WcfService1.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.vb" %>
```

Which, incidentally, has a long blue squiggly line indicating "Unrecognized configuration section services. (E:\projects\TestJquery\WcfService1\web.config line 35) "  so I need something else here - another project reference?

Here's the complete web.config file (the only thing that changed was the recommended addition of the "services" section)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="Service1">
      <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
          contract="Service1.IService1"/>
      <endpoint 
        address="mex"
        binding="mexHttpBinding" 
        contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</configuration>
```

I figure, if I could just get the default WCF webservice project to work, I could better dissect and understand what is going on. If anyone has done this, please send a zip file of your working, functioning default VS2012 solution (or a link).  I really want to get away from ASMX web services, the lexicon of WCF doesn't seem to make any sense.

web.config changes - still no workie, but no blue squigglies :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior"  name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding= "basicHttpBinding"
           />
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

FINAL WEB.CONFIG settings necessary for default, out of the box, VS2012 WCF Web Service Application to work. I hope this helps all the newbies like me to at least have something to tweak with while learning WCF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding= "basicHttpBinding"
            contract="WcfService1.IService1"
           />
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Your service endpoint refers to a binding configuration that doesn't exist in the web.config - `jsonpBinding`.  You need to define that binding in the config (in the `<system.serviceModel><bindings>` section.

Comment: Also, your `<services>` and `<behaviors>` sections go under the `<system.serviceModel>` section, not outside of it.  The default project in 2012 should work out of the box with absolutely no changes.

Comment: I'd also recommend googling for WCF service tutorials, rather than trying to figure it out by reverse-engineering an existing project.  WCF can have a steep learning curve (though once you learn it, it's pretty straight forward, IMO).

Comment: <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="Service1">
getting attribute name invalid, and a few more errors after putting this in the correct spot. There's more errors, hold on

Comment: "the binding configuration attribute is invalid" "the contract attribute is invalid".
I would love to see a tutorial that actually covers all the extra configurations that are needed to get WCF to work, trial & error is faster once I have something that works to use. MSDN is useless.

Comment: Looking for a bindings settings reference in Google - this could take a while. :)

Comment: You're getting those errors because the tags are in the wrong part of the config file.  With WCF 4.0 and later it's actually possible to host a service with nothing in the configuration file.  I disagree that MSDN is useless, but to each their own on that one.

Comment: they're in the right place now. The name for the service should have been WcfService1.Service1 - the blue squigglies went away.
as per MSDN, I deleted the contract="" in the endpoint, then changed the binding="basicHttpBinding". Naturally, it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: It doesn't work because now you have defined an endpoint without a contract.  Try removing the entire `<system.serviceModel>` section from the config file and then see if it works.  If you haven't changed anything else, it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's a number of things.  As I said in the comments, the project should work **without** changes just fine out of the box.

The main issue in your posted code is that your web.config is not correct - you have the `<services>` and `<behaviors>` section outside of the `<system.serviceModel>` section, which is why you're getting the errors you're seeing.  Additionally, the closing tags for your behaviors are in the wrong order.

What your config **should** look like is this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyServiceBinding" />
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="MyServiceBinding"
                contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Note that I removed your custom binding and for purposes of illustration used `wsHttpBinding` and named the configuration `MyServiceBinding`.  This will result in the service using that configuration section for binding information (and since I didn't set any values, it will be the defaults for that binding).

You could remove the entire service model section of the config and hit F5, and you will get a service that is exposed over a default `basicHttpBinding` endpoint.

**Added**

WCF is complex and has a steep learning curve.  Binding configuration alone is a big subject, and probably one of the biggest causes of problems for developers in WCF.  Remember the ABC's of WCF - Address, Binding and Contract.  You **must** have all three to have successful running service.

With WCF 4.0 Microsoft implemented the concept of default endpoints, bindings, etc to make configuration easier, and they added additional stuff in 4.5.  Take a look at [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for a starter.

Comment: <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding= "basicHttpBinding"
            contract="WcfService1.IService1"
           />
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

Comment: And...?  You're giving me snippets of code without context.  All you have in the code above is exactly what you'll get if you didn't have the `<system.serviceModel>` section at all.  A default endpoint with the default binding for `http` - `basicHttpBinding`.

Comment: the service name must include the root namespace (the project name in this case) - making it "WcfService1.Service1"
The binding should be (for http, not customized) set to "basicHttpBinding". I made a mistake with the contract - the address is EMPTY for use in VS2012 (Cassini will figure that out for you as per MSDN). The contract is also the root namespace dotted with the interface name - WcfService1.IService1 (note the default naming including the letter I - for Interface)

Comment: I know all of that :)  What I meant was With the changes, does it still not work?  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: it works now. - the placement of the settings in the web.config were a good start and putting the correct name of the service and contracts were the other culprit. Thanks!